# Enter keypress is not detected on keypress function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying to detect enter key press inside tinmyce editor and it's working fine for all the keys but its not working for enter key.

```
setup : function (instance) {
     instance.on("keypress", function(e) {
             var Keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
             alert(Keycode);

       });
}
```

In above code its alerting all the keys except ENTER. i don't know whats the issue there.

Comment: Things like `keypress`, `keyCode`, and `which` are deprecated and do not have guaranteed consistent behaviour.

Comment: so what can i use in the place of keyCode ? @gcampbell . i want to detect when enter key is pressed

Comment: updated answer @TariqHusain

Comment: @TariqHusain try now..

Comment: @TariqHusain I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer, as keydown worked for you...thanks

Answer (score 3):

keypress wasn't working for me , but keydown worked for me.

```
setup : function (instance) {
     instance.on("keydown", function(e) {
             var Keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
             alert(Keycode);

       });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work, i've tested it and it works in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/xonL8v1x/) with jquery 2.24

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    console.log('You pressed enter!');
  } else {
    console.log('You pressed ' + e.which);
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 

</body>
```

EDIT: Sorry i only noticed after that this was also tagged as tinymce

I think you can do this by slightly adjusting your function

```
//tinyMCE.init({
 setup : function(instance) {
      instance.onKeyDown.add(function(instance, event) {

          if (event.keyCode == 13)  {  //enter
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
             //do stuff here
            //alert("Enter!");
          }
          else{ alert (event.keyCode);}
      });
   }
//});
```

EDIT 2:
In the current [tiny mce docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup), there is an example of a function [in setup].

maybe try

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  setup: function(instance) {
    instance.on('keypress', function(e) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13)  {  //enter
                  event.preventDefault();
                  event.stopPropagation();
                 //do stuff here
                //alert("Enter!");
              }
              else{ alert (event.keyCode);}
    });
  }
});
```

note the tinymce is now all lowercase..

Comment: We can not use $(document) inside tinymc editor. it wont going to work

Comment: btw, keycode is not yet deprecated, it's alternative 'key' has not yet been implemented. It currently only has support on chrome (desktop only, vsns 51+)  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: instance.onKeyDown.add this throws error in 4.0 tinyMCE version. it works in 3.x version

Comment: is there any other solution ?

Comment: Thanks @Rachel Gallen for the help , i have used keydown that worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
    
        $(function () {
            $("#MYTEXTBOX").keyup(function (e) {
                alert(e.keyCode);
            });
        });

Answer (score 0):

onkeypress does not detect some special keys like ctrl, shift arrow keys etc. Use onkeypress or onekyup instead.